# Why does py.test pass a unittest when Pyunit and nosetest fail it (as expected)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm a complete new starter when it comes to writing python unittests and I know it's far far better and easier to write the tests before the code but I thought I'd start by contributing to a github project and fixing a few small issues and giving it a go.

One issue I was fixing was that if a argument wasn't given to an method, it would actually remove the argument on the server. I should mention that this project is a client for a REST API. This was easy enough to fix but I thought it would be good to write a test for it.

The code of the broken method is included within a class:

```py
def edit_device(self, device, nickname=None, model=None, manufacturer=None):
    data = {"nickname": nickname}
    iden = device.device_iden
    r = self._session.post("{}/{}".format(self.DEVICES_URL, iden), data=json.dumps(data))
```

I then was going to use `Mock` to mock the responses of the REST API using their documentation as the guide (it includes example responses).

The issue I am having is I have written my test as:

```py
@mock.patch('pushbullet.pushbullet.requests.Session.get', side_effect=mocked_requests_get)
@mock.patch('pushbullet.pushbullet.requests.Session.post', side_effect=mocked_requests_post)
class TestPushbullet(object):

    def test_edit_device_without_nickname(self, mock_get, mock_post):
        pb = pushbullet.Pushbullet("API_KEY")
        device = pb.devices[0]
        new_device = pb.edit_device(device)
        assert new_device.nickname == device.nickname
```

This seems to work correctly, the methods `mocked_requests_get` and `mocked_requests_post` get called. If I run this test within eclipse PyDev using pyUnit to run the pytest - it fails, as I expect. If I run the tests using nose it also fails, again perfect. If I run the test using py.test on the command line, it passes.

If I use the `pytest.set_trace()` as the first line in `mocked_requests_post` I can print `args` and it shows that the nickname is in fact not None and still set to what it is on the server (i.e. device.nickname so the assertion passes)

I can't for the life of me work out why py.test is not picking up the change in json from the `self._session.post`. If I change the iden in the URL format, it does indeed pick up that change, however changing the data body it does not.

Am I doing something intrinsically wrong? I can't see why py.test would pass and nose would fail on the same code.

EDIT: on the command line I'm running `py.test path/to/single_test_file.py` and the test file has only the single test method I've pasted above.

Comment: Have you isolate this specific test (only that method) to separated file?

Comment: As I was coding for the fix, it's the only test in the file. Only other code is the mock code I didn't paste, that sends back my fake response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out, I must have installed the client package into python previous to deciding to write the tests. It looks like the command line `py.test` was therefore reading the client package from the true source (via pip install) whereas the IDE was reading it from the development package I had in eclipse.

Solution is to remove the package: `pip uninstall <package>`
Reinstall the development package: `pip install -e .` (when in the root development directory)